# require(MYSQL); error in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have created a simple index.php script that will display the header and footer, but I keep on getting error in the code that I can't resolve
here is my code.

This file is called mysql.inc.php :

```
<?php
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'ecommerce1');
$dbc =mysqli_connect (DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');
function escape_data ($data, $dbc){
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $data =stripslashes($data);
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim ($data));
}?>
```

This is the config.inc.php :

```
<?php
if (!defined('LIVE')) DEFINE('LIVE', false);
DEFINE('CONTACT_EMAIL', 'you@example.com');
define ('BASE_URI', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\.');
define ('BASE_URL', 'localhost/ecommerce/html/index.php');
define ('MYSQL', BASE_URI . 'mysql.inc.php');
session_start();
function my_error_handler($e_number, $e_message, $e_file, $e_line,        $e_vars) {
    $message = "An error occurred in script '$e_file' on line $e_line:\n$e_message\n";
    $message .= "<pre>" .print_r(debug_backtrace(), 1) . "</pre>\n";
    if (!LIVE) { 
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . nl2br($message) . '</div>';
    } else { 
        error_log ($message, 1, CONTACT_EMAIL, 'From:admin@example.com');
        if ($e_number != E_NOTICE) {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">A system error occurred. We apologize for the inconvenience.</div>';
        }
    }
    return true; 
} 
function redirect_invalid_user($check = 'user_id', $destination = 'index.php', $protocol = 'http://') {
    // Check for the session item:
    if (!isset($_SESSION[$check])) {
        $url = $protocol . BASE_URL . $destination; // Define the URL.
        header("Location: $url");
        exit(); // Quit the script.
    }
} ?>
```

This is the index.php :

```
<?php
require('./includes/config.inc.php');
require(MYSQL);
include('./includes/header.html');
?><h1>
    Welcome
</h1>
<?php /* PAGE CONTENT ENDS HERE! */
include('./includes/footer.html');
?>
```

[This is the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2y2Q.jpg)
[Here is my project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq6bs.jpg)

Comment: whats the permission on that fie ?

Comment: @MiteshPant i set it  as ALL PRIVILEGES

Comment: "Magic quotes" was removed in PHP 5.4, and that call to `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` is probably a huge mistake. Don't use `stripslashes`, *especially* when working with databases. Likewise, get rid of that atrocious `escape_data` function and use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like your path has an extra dot before mysql.inc.php  try removing the dot at the end of your BASE_URI

Comment: i was able to resolve the error i removed the dot and added double slash like this define ('BASE_URI', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\\'); if i use one slash it wont work thank you for the help